# Array List not finding objects

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a feature where two current objects can be saved so next time they can be loaded instead of being created again. I have a problem with following class:

```
public class Investor implements Serializable {

        private String investorName;
        private double investorCapital;
        private ArrayList<Share> shareOwned;
        private ArrayList<Integer> numberOwned;

        public Investor(String name, double capital) {
            investorName = name;
            investorCapital = capital;
            shareOwned = new ArrayList<Share>();
            numberOwned = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
```

P.S. I removed function just to show structure. Then I execute following code:

```
File investorData = new File("inv1.ser");

 if(investorData.exists()) {
            try {
                FileInputStream loadData = new FileInputStream(investorData);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(loadData);
                inv1 = (Investor) ois.readObject();
                loadData.close();
                ois.close();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occurred", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?", "Creating new investor", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                double capital = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your investor capital?", "Creating new investor", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                inv1 = new Investor(name, capital);
            }
            catch(NullPointerException exc) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter details in order to proceed", "File Not Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New investor " + inv1.getInvestorName() + " with balance: " + inv1.getInvestorCapital() + " has been successfully created!", "Investor Created", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            try {
                FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream(investorData);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
                oos.writeObject(inv1);
                saveFile.close();
                oos.close();
            }
            catch(Exception exc) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occurred", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
```

When I launch program first time it prompts me to create new Investor object which it does successfully and saves in appropriate location and so on. After that I can use program: buy/sell shares etc, but once I close it, and open again, it doesn't recognize shares that were bought before. So for example if when I closed I had Gold - 100, then when I open program again it will show Gold - 100 and will try to buy 10 more, it will add new Gold object to shareOwned and I will have Gold - 100, Gold - 10. So as I understand it cannot recognize old Gold object and added new one (as was intended if it never existed).

I cannot upload a whole program because it is quite big, there is buyShare method in investor class:

```
public void buyShare(double price, int amount, Share stock) {
        investorCapital -= price * amount;
        if(shareOwned.contains(stock)) {
            numberOwned.add(shareOwned.indexOf(stock), numberOwned.get(shareOwned.indexOf(stock)) + amount);
        }
        else {
            shareOwned.add(stock);
            numberOwned.add(amount);
        }
    }
```

Share class(without functions):

```
public class Share implements Serializable {

    private String shareName;
    private double shareValue;
    private int shareAvailable;
    private final double SHARE_PURE_VALUE;

    public Share(String name, double value, int available) {
        shareName = name;
        SHARE_PURE_VALUE = value;
        shareValue = value / available;
        shareValue = Math.round(shareValue * 10) / 10;
        shareAvailable = available;
    }
```

You can see where I check for "contains" it should return just add numberOwned, but instead it creates new one, so it cannot find previous Gold that was saved before. Sorry for explaining so badly, I can send a program if that will be more convenient.

Comment: Dont publish all, just make a minimal reproducer. It will most likely make find the error yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you expect to have "Gold - 110", not "Gold - 100, Gold - 10", right?

So, I think you have to implement equals and hashCode methods on Share class. When "shareOwned.contains(stock)" is called, never returns true, correct?

That's why you always have a new stock object in your list.

Add [commons-lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to your project and put this code on your Share class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Yes, that is correct! It proceeds to else, which is for when share does not exist

Comment: I changed my answer above to add a possibile solution for your problem.

Comment: You don't have to implement `hashCode()` for `ArrayList`.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much! I solved the problem. As it was mentioned I had to override equals() and hashCode() methods in Share class and now everything working (seems at least) perfectly. I was trying to use loops to check names instead but this solution is much simpler!

```
@Override

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Share share = (Share) o;

        if (!shareName.equals(share.shareName)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 1;
        }

        public void setMarketValue() {
            shareValue = SHARE_PURE_VALUE / shareAvailable;
            shareValue = Math.round(shareValue * 10) / 10;
        }
```

Comment: You didn't solve the problem. @dansouza solved the problem. There is no need to just reiterate his answer. You don't have to implement `hashCode()` for `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yes I thanked him, but I just used shareName variable instead of using EqualsBuilder have you even looked at our answers? @EJP